# Entity Framework : a way to override naming convention globally?

Tags: entity-framework, customization, naming-conventions

We have a project having to be linked to a heavy database infrastructure (10+ years living), on which a lot of tools are yet running in various ways.

The main software has his own convention model to handle foreign keys and primary keys, unfortunatly its a little bit different than the EF conventions.

EF : table "Course" has a PK named "ID" or "CourseID"
Us : table "Courses" is pluralized and has a PK named "nID"

EF : table "PlayerInscription" has a FK named "CourseID" to the table "Course"
US : table "PlayerInscriptions" is pluralized and has a FK named "nCOURSE_ID" to the table "Courses"

I know that I can override case by case on each entity the keys, but for this big project it involves a lot of tables, relational keys and it results on a very heavy work and extra notations.

Do you know if it exists a way to override the EF convention for a whole project, to let databasefirst manage the models more "fluently" than with all annotations ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace NamingConventionTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDbContext dbctx = new MyDbContext();
            var c = new Course()
            {
                SomeStringProp = "test",
                SomeIntProp = 1
            };

        dbctx.Set<Course>().Add(c);
        dbctx.SaveChanges();


    }

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Properties<int>()
                        .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("ID"))
                        .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new IdConvention());
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        public class IdConvention : Convention
        {
            public IdConvention()
            {
                this.Properties<int>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Id"))
                    .Configure(x => x.HasColumnName("asdID"));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeStringProp { get; set; }
        public int SomeIntProp { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```